# Using Integrated security for DB connection in Google Docs Script?

Tags: sql-server, google-docs, integrated-security

I want to establish a connection to MS SQL in Google docs via Script by using `integrated security = SSIP`, basically connecting to the server with my integrated Windows authentication. However, Google tells me that the 'integrated security' connection property is unsupported. I tried phrasing it differently (trusted_security etc.) but nothing works.

Does anyone know a workaround?

I used the query google offered below.

```js
// Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'database_IP_address';
var user = 'user_name';
var userPwd = 'user_password';
var db = 'database_name';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db' integrated security = ssip;

// Read up to 1000 rows of data from the table and log them.
function readFromTable() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM entries');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

Comment: You should clarify if this is about MySQL or ms sql server. The question says ms sql server, the JDBC connection says MySQL. The two are not the same. MySQL by default does not support integrated authentication. You need a commercial authentication plugin for that.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even notice. Yes, it's SQL server I am talking about. So, is your answer implying that MySQL can't and SQL Server can?

Comment: Yep, ms sql server can do integrated authentication